# How to replace values in JSON file and append it with Response

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file like this.

```
{
   "Get_Request_1": {
      "FindRequest": {
         "CompanyIdentifiers_typehint": [
            "CompanyIdentifiers"
         ],
         "CompanyIdentifiers": [
            {
               "RIC": {
                  "Value": "MSFT.O"
               }
            }
         ],
      }
   }
}
```

I am fetching data using an API call using the below function:

```
def RetrieveQuotes(token, appid):
    quoteRequestMsg = json.load(open('Get_Request_1.json'))
    
    quoteURL = 'http://api.abcd.com/api/Developments/Developments.svc/REST/Developments_1/Developments_1'
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
               'ApplicationID': appid, 'Token': token}
    quoteResult = doSendRequest(quoteURL, quoteRequestMsg, headers)
    if quoteResult and quoteResult.status_code == 200:
        print('Quote response message: ')
        #print(quoteResult.json())
        #print(json.dumps(quoteResult.json(), sort_keys=True,indent=2, separators=(',', ':')))
    with open('quoteResult.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(quoteResult.text,f)
```

The above script is working fine. Now i have 5 companies for which i need to fetch the data. The data values are present in the data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('Company_List.xlsx')
print(df)

          Company Name Ticker
0    Microsoft Corp    MSFT.O
1             ABB Ltd.   ABBN
2  Abbott Laboratories  ABT.N
3          AbbVie Inc.   ABBV
4        Accenture plc  ACN.N
```

How do i loop through the `df['Ticker']` and append it to the resulting response JSON.?
I am new to python and learning these things gradually. I have tried the following.

```
def RetrieveQuotes(token, appid):
    quoteRequestM

    sg = {
       "Get_Request_1": {
          "FindRequest": {
             "CompanyIdentifiers_typehint": [
                "CompanyIdentifiers"
             ],
             "CompanyIdentifiers": [
                {
                   "RIC": {
                      "Value": "MSFT.O"
                   }
                }
             ],
          }
       }
    }
        
        quoteURL = 'http://api.abcd.com/api/Developments/Developments.svc/REST/Developments_1/Get_Developments_1'
        headers = {'content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                   'ApplicationID': appid, 'Token': token}
        print('############### Sending Quote request message to TRKD ###############')
        import pandas as pd
        df = pd.read_excel('Company_List.xlsx')
        for i in df['Ticker']:
            tmp=i
            quoteRequestMsg["Get_Request_1"]["FindRequest"]["CompanyIdentifiers"][0]['RIC']=tmp
            quoteResult = doSendRequest(quoteURL, quoteRequestMsg, headers)
            #print(quoteResult)
            quoteResult.append(quoteResult)
            if quoteResult and quoteResult.status_code == 200:
                print('Quote response message: ')
                #print(quoteResult.json())
                #print(json.dumps(quoteResult.json(), sort_keys=True,indent=2, separators=(',', ':')))
            with open('quoteResult.json', 'w') as f:
                json.dump(quoteResult.text,f)
```

Comment: what do you mean by "append it to the resulting response JSON"?

Comment: I mean when i fetch the first data from API it get stored in a response JSON file and then when the 2nd data is fetch it should be append the result to the created JSON File.

Comment: if you will try to append directly to JSON file then you create incorrect JSON file. You have to read all data from JSON file, append new values and save all data back to JSON file. Maybe it will be easier to get all results as list and later write it all to file.

Comment: Thanks! Can you help me with that?